# "Mr. John s/o Mr. Wagner" vs "Mr. John s/o Mr. & Mrs. Wagner"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, abbreviations, writing-style

Which one below is correct?

> Mr. John s/o Mr. Wagner
>   OR
>   Mr. John s/o Mr. & Mrs. Wagner

Is it necessary to affix Mr. & Mrs. in this case? It seems superfluous to add Mrs. because a child is always of a Mr. & Mrs.

Answer (score 2):

Is a child always the child of Mr and Mrs X? What about unmarried couples, single mothers and cases where the wife does not take the husband's surname? At least in the west and other areas where these are not uncommon cases it is safer to be specific if there could be any doubt. I am also a little concerned about "Mr John" as, unless John is his surname, it is uncommon to use Mr with first name and not surname. I would recommend either

"Mr. John Wagner s/o Mr. & Mrs. Wagner"
c.f. "Mr John Wagner s/o Mr. Hislop & Mrs. Merton"

what about
"Mr John Wagner s/o Mr. & Mr. Merton"?

it is very uncommon for s/o to be used in British English (not sure about US) and even in formal situations it has become very rare that someone's parentage is mentioned unless their parents are more well known than they are or if it is pertinent to the point being made. Why do you need this construct? It is an uncommon and gawky construct to (UK) English speaking(?) ears.

Comment: You might use it in the Forthcoming Marriages column of *The Times.*

Comment: fair point and afaik (more of an FT reader) that is traditionally of the form "Mr John Wagner s/o Mr. Ian Hislop & Mrs. Paul Hislop nee Merton" isn't it? (no prizes for where I'm getting my names from!)

Answer (score 0):

Mr. John s/o Mr. Wagner is correct. Whatever be the case, a child is never born of asexual reproduction.

Comment: what about those instances where the mother is't a Mrs. Wagner?

Comment: not my downvote btw

Comment: That's what I meant to say that sentence looks good generally. If Mr. Wagner is the father and Mrs. Thompson is the mother, who cares, he will still be s/o Mr. Wagner. I am not so good in english, but this is more of common sense. If Mr. Thompson adopted John, then you can say "Mr John s/o Mr. Thompson", you don't need to be sensitive or informative about it.

Comment: "If Mr. Wagner is the father and Mrs. Thompson is the mother, who cares, he will still be s/o Mr. Wagner." - he will also be s/o Mrs. Thompson... or is she not important enough to mention? If you are going to say s/o one parent you ought to mention the other surely?

Comment: You can say s/o Mrs Thompson...you don't need to mention the name of both the parents until asked so..

Comment: 1) the question is about a situation calling for both and 2) I'm running a one man campaign to get women better recognized in their own right when talking about their children. The misogyny on this site is terrible.

Comment: In that case better take first name(or full name) of both the parents. You can say s/o of Julliet and Romeo...I was saying in a general context..for example I know Mrs Jennie Thompson but I don't know about Wagner, I would better say John as S/O Jennie. I would not be very interested in knowing and mentioning his father's name...